# Retriving all checks, deposits, etc dealing with money using qbxml

Tags: quickbooks, qbxml

I'm able to retrieve some data using QBXML from a QuickBooks 14 database, but there are missing items in the returned XML. For example, although all of the General Journal Entries are returned, but not Checks or Deposits. This gives and incomplete picture of the account's balance.

Is `JournalEntryQueryRq` the best way to get all of the information? If so are there other child nodes than `<IncludeLineItems>true</IncludeLineItems>` I should use? Should something else other than `JournalEntryQueryRq`be used to begin with?

Here is a current XML sample for an account

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?qbxml version="13.0"?>
<QBXML>
  <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
    <!-- Examples: -->
    <JournalEntryQueryRq>
      <AccountFilter>

        <ListID>80000000-1xxxxxxxxx</ListID>
      </AccountFilter>
      <IncludeLineItems>true</IncludeLineItems>
    </JournalEntryQueryRq>



  </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

that returns a lot of data for the account, but none of the types Check or Deposit. This makes me think I'm missing something easy.

Thanks in advance for any insight

Answer (score 1):

The `JournalEntryQueryRq` request returns `Journal Entry` records.

If you want `Check` objects, do a `CheckQueryRq`.

If you want `Deposit` objects, do a `DepositQueryRq`.

All of the syntax is documented in the QuickBooks OSR:

- https://developer-static.intuit.com/qbsdk-current/common/newosr/index.html

Comment: That's a bummer, I thought JournalEntries would contain all of the data. I don't think I can send a request for just "Give me the checks for this listID" to QuickBooks. I take it from your comment that's not the case.